# Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/drawer" from "App.js" React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new in React Native and i am tyring to use "navigation/menu bar",But i am getting following error

```
Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/drawer" from "App.js"
```

I installed but still getting same error,Where i am wrong ? Here is my code
Here is my current code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: @GauravRoy: means ? How can i share this ?

Comment: like expo snack is a website where you can share working exampe of your code,p lease share

Comment: @GauravRoy: sure sir, give me some minutes then

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the main project folder while running the install command

**npm**

```
npm i react-navigation/drawer
```

**yarn**

```
yarn add react-navigation/drawer
```

try also installing your package without the @